# SSH File Copy - publickey is not allowed

Tags: azure-devops

Got our own build/release pool for Linux servers.  I've got a task in a pipeline to copy files via ssh to a remote server.

On the build server, as the service account user the agent runs as, I run `ssh-keygen`.  Hit enter on all the questions.

I copy the build agents `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote server.

I make sure the permissions are set accordingly on the remote server (user rw only).

On the build server, as the build agent I run:

```
ssh user@remoteserver
```

And I'm logged in without a password.  Awesome!  key exchange worked!

I then create a Service Connection in Azure DevOps and in my 'Copy Files over SSH' task, I specify that service connection with the remote user to use and I supply the private key of the remote servers user.

The pipeline fails:

```
2019-08-09T21:15:05.7510316Z ##[error]Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: All configured authentication methods failed..`
```

I enable `DEBUG3` mode on the remote server and see this message in the logs:

```
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x560ecb33c5f0
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 52139/52139 (e=0/0)
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug1: trying public key file /home/buildagent/.ssh/authorized_keys
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug1: fd 9 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug2: key not found
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x560ecb33c5f0 is not allowed
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: Failed publickey for buildagent from 10.251.80.6 port 57726 ssh2: RSA SHA256:PTyAT4hagIZCh2QM8lDvOneF0BIlu6wCiGdfH/Ro5no
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
Aug  9 15:16:54 vwc1uewbapp52 sshd[63105]: debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password" [preauth]
```

Why does it work manually, using the same users but not when run as a pipeline?

Comment: If I move it away from a SSH task to an inline bash script that does ssh remotely, everything works.

This makes me think there's a compatibility issue between my servers SSHD configuration and the security settings on the client that the SSH task is using.